# Problem with INSERT INTO SELECT SQL (Access, VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

"Number of query values and destination fields are not the same" on my command:

```
INSERT INTO TransactionHistory (
    [TransactionNumber]
    ,[UniqueID]
    ,[Replica_UniqueID]
    ,[FullName]
    ,[BusName]
    ,[PlateNumber]
    ,[Location]
    ,[Destination]
    ,[Price]
    ,[TimeOut]
    ,[DateOut]
    ,[DateTimeOfTransaction]
    ,[TypeOfTransaction]
    )
VALUES (
    " & TransactionNum & "
    ,(
        SELECT UniqueID
            ,Replica_UniqueID
            ,FullName
            ,BusName
            ,PlateNumber
            ,Location
            ,Destination
            ,Paid
            ,TimeOfDeparture
            ,DateOfDeparture
        FROM BusPassengers
        WHERE BusName = '" & BusName & "'
        )
    ,'" & DateTimeToday & "'
    ,'" & TransactionType & "'
    ) ""
```

> TransactionNum is an Integer, while DateTimeToday is Date, and TransactionType is string

Thank you!

Im trying to copy a table from another table, and generate a transaction number which will be inserted and copy on the another table.

Comment: you cant do that with your sub query.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you have any suggestion on how to do it? Appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build them into the SELECT:

```
"INSERT INTO TransactionHistory (
    [TransactionNumber]
    ,[UniqueID]
    ,[Replica_UniqueID]
    ,[FullName]
    ,[BusName]
    ,[PlateNumber]
    ,[Location]
    ,[Destination]
    ,[Price]
    ,[TimeOut]
    ,[DateOut]
    ,[DateTimeOfTransaction]
    ,[TypeOfTransaction]
    )
SELECT "
& TransactionNum  & 
", UniqueID
, Replica_UniqueID
, FullName
, BusName
, PlateNumber
, Location
, Destination
, Paid
, TimeOfDeparture
, DateOfDeparture
,'" & DateTimeToday & "'
,'" & TransactionType & "'
 FROM BusPassengers
 WHERE BusName = '" & BusName & "'"
```

make sure that DateTimeToday is formatted correctly (you could also use the SQL current datetime function Now())